# mapreduce data splitting based on time

Tags: mapreduce

Am parsing the mlabs data from google, parsed data will give text record for each packet of data. I want to split the data for half an hour so that what goes to reducer is an half an hour data. Is this the best way to get half an hour data or is there a better way. Can anyone suggest how can i do that.

Parsed data will be in the format:

```
src            dest         startTime        endTime        bytesTransferred
34.456.67.88   23.456.78.9   3453453454555   3453453994555   4564
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the first second of the 30 minute (1800 seconds) epoch timsestamp as the key emitted by the Map and the value is the data record (or the parsed fields of same that you care about).

In that way on the Reducer  will see (key, List[DataRecord]) like this:

```
 (30-minute-interval-One-start-second) [(Data Record 1a, Data Record 1b, ... Data Record 1k)]
 (30-minute-interval-Two-start-second) [(Data Record 2a, Data Record 2b, ... Data Record 2k)]
...
```

Comment: The purpose of splitting the data is i want to save 30 minutes data as a record. Now i cannot generate key for half an hour as each file is having data only for 10 sec. So how can i collect data for 30 minutes.

Comment: You can perform aggregation for each 30 minute interaval within the reducer. So in your case the "aggregation" is to transform 180 ten second records in each list into one record.  Now AFA the "collecting for 30 minutes" that is handled automatically when you choose the (30-minute-interva-<1|2|3|..>-start-second) as the key. You do need to calculate that key for each record in the mapper in order to emit the correct one.